# Replace DataFrame column with nested dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to replace the 'starters' column of this DataFrame

```
             starters
roster_id         
Bob            3086
Bob            1234
Cam            6130
...            ...
```

with  the player names from a large nested dict like this. The values in my 'starters' column are the keys.

```
{
  "3086": {
    "team": "NE",
    "player_id":"3086",
    "full_name": "tombrady",
     },
  "1234": {
    "team": "SEA",
    "player_id":"1234",
    "full_name": "RussellWilson",
     },
  "6130": {
    "team": "BUF",
    "player_id":"6130",
    "full_name": "DevinSingletary",
     },

  ...
}
```

I tried using DataFrame.replace(dict) and Dataframe.map(dict) but that gives me back all the player info instead of just the name.

is there a way to do this with a nested dict? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let df be the dataframe and d be the dictionary, then you can use `apply` from pandas on `axis 1` to change the column

```
df.apply(lambda x: d[str(x.starters)]['full_name'], axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks this helped! im fairly new at python so didn't think of a lambda function. worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understand your question correctly. Have you tried using dict['full_name'] instead of simply dict?

Answer (score 0):

Try `pd.concat` with `series.map`:

```
>>> pd.concat([
        df,
        pd.DataFrame.from_records(
                  df.astype(str)
                    .starters
                    .map(dct)
                    .values
              ).set_index(df.index)
    ], axis=1)

           starters team player_id        full_name
roster_id                                          
Bob            3086   NE      3086         tombrady
Bob            1234  SEA      1234    RussellWilson
Cam            6130  BUF      6130  DevinSingletary
```